# Can't add dependency Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I'm having problem importing ActionbarSherlock in my project.It's added in my build.gradle but when I extend my Activity to SherlockActivity in my project, Android Studio doesn't show actionbarsherlock.

This is my build.gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock-fest:4.4.0@jar'
```

}

and in my external library has the jar file of actionabrsherlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

`compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'`

This automatically gets ActionBarSherlock from Maven Central. You can remove your downloaded JAR file too.

In general, [Gradle, please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) makes it super easy to add dependencies to your project.

Comment: Thanks! :D Last question why does it add  com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock-fest:4.4.0@jar instead of  com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar when I add it via maven repo

Comment: Hmm, do you mean that `com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock-fest:4.4.0@jar` appears in External Libraries?